# Why getting null written inside the logger while using it inside python script?

Tags: python, logging

I am using logger in my python script as :

```
import logger
logging.basicConfig(filename='sample.log',level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.info("helllo")
```

Now there are many functions inside the python script and every time i have to use a logger i need to mention following line :

```
logging.basicConfig(filename='sample.log',level=logging.DEBUG)
```

again and again. In order to resolve this i declared function which returns logger object as follows:

```
class sample()
    def set_log(self):
            l = logging.getLogger(logger_name)
            l.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
            formatter = logging.Formatter(' %(levelname)s : %(message)s')
            fileHandler = logging.FileHandler("c:/sample.log", mode='w')
            fileHandler.setFormatter(formatter)
            streamHandler = logging.StreamHandler()
            streamHandler.setFormatter(formatter)    
            l.addHandler(fileHandler)
            return l
      def func(self):
            log = self.set_log()
            log.info("hsdhkhd")
```

Now i am using set_log() inside func() but what happens is it sometimes it inserts NUll at various locations inside the log but actually null should not get entered. So, why is it that i am getting null inside the log files sometimes?

Comment: [`logging.getLogger()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.getLogger)?

Comment: The constructor should be more like this: def __init__(self, variable1, varriable2, logging)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to call `logging.basicConfig()` each time, no. You only need to call it *once*. The `logging.basicConfig()` function always returns `None`, so you can't use it to access a `Logger.info()` method anyway.

You can always access the root logger (in configured state) with `logging.getLogger()`. That's because the `logging` module uses *singletons*, global state, to configure all logging operations.

The convention is to store a global reference to a logger in your module:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

Here the module name is used to indicate where log messages come from, and this also lets you adjust configuration per module.

However, subsequent calls to `logging.getLogger(somename)` will always return the same singleton logger object (not passing in the name gives you the root `Logger` in the hierarchy).

At any rate, the top-level `logging.info()` function just delegates to the root logger, it is equivalent to `logging.getLogger().info()`. It does call `logging.basicConfig()` *if it wasn't already called before*.

---

Your updated sample function will add new `FileHandler()` and `StreamHandler()` instance to the singleton `logger_name` logger object each time `self.set_log()` is called. That'll lead to undefined results you re-open the file (truncating it each time).

Stick to calling `basicConfig()` **once**, at the start of your program. The rest of your code should only concern themselves with direct `logging.getLogger()` calls.

Comment: @Martjin i have added a function (edited the question)which returns logger object but when i use this function i sometimes get null written inside the log but there are actuall values. so, why is it behaviour that sometimes it adds null to the log?

Comment: @newlearner: why are you re-defining a log object *each and every time*? Don't do this. The `logging` module keeps track of the object *for you*. All you have to do is give it a name and keep asking for it: `logging.getLogger(name)`.

Comment: @newlearner: your code keeps adding more and more `StreamHandler` instances. That'll certainly lead to weird results.

Comment: thank you for the elaborate answer, it helped me as well!